# Nodejs: How to search for a substring within an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, substring

Assuming that I have an array that looks like the one below:

```
["file1.java", "file32.js", "file44.java", "file4.html", "file15.js"]
```

I would like to filter out only the elements that end in ".java". Therefore I would like to somehow be able to search for the substring ".java" as I'm iterating through each element in my array. How do I go about doing this? Thank you

Comment: If you need to filter out elements that end in java, you'd have to use a regex as you iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of the `Array` type:

```
var files = ["file1.java", "file32.js", "file44.java", "file4.html", "file15.js"];
var filtered = files.filter(function(item) {
        return item.endsWith(".java");
    }
);
console.log(filtered);
```